# SQL server regex grouping

Tags: sql-server, regex, grouping

i am trying to figure out why this comparison doesnt work

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] where [FIELDNAME] like '(*|*8PH*)'
```

where as '*' and '*8PH*' are possible values of that field.
ive been looking into stack overflow and the web for normal guides with examples for sql server regex with not much success
thank you

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but isn't using `LIKE *` logically the same as saying that anything matches?

Answer (score 0):

Like doesn't take a regex parameter. It takes a pattern parameter, which is different. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

What you want sounds like this

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] where [FIELDNAME] = '*' or [FIELDNAME] = '8PH';
```